# Unable to bind collection to ComboBox in silverlight

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, combobox

I've a `ObservableCollection`, when I want to display this `ObservableCollection` with `CheckBox` I am simply binding the contents to `CheckBox` but when I want to display the same collection by using `ComboBox` I am unable to do that. Any suggestions?

XAML: Display collection using `CheckBox` --WORKS

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Synonyms}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--Display items in CheckBox-->
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Display}" Margin="10,0,0,0" /> // Display is the collection.
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Output:

[image]

XAML: Display collection using `ComboBox` --NOTHING OVER HERE

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Synonyms}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

           <!--Display items in ComboBox.-->
            Approach - 1
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Display}"/>
            </ComboBox>

            Approach - 2
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Synonyms}" DisplayMemberPath="Display"/>

            Approach - 3
            <ComboBox >
              <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                 <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Display,StringFormat='Display: {0}'}" />
                 </Border>
               </DataTemplate>
              </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Output:

[image]

I want to display items(one,two,three, etc.) inside oneComboBox with Select All option. I've tried several approaches but nothing. What am I missing here?

Comment: You may need to add the SelectedValue attribute

Comment: @TimFreese I tried but didn't work.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve...you want four combo boxes (created from a list of four items) each with a different value per item?

Comment: No. I just want one ComboBox with all items from List. Whether its four items or 10. All of them should appear inside one combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox is not designed to hold multiple items unlike the Combobox so implementing a system designed for the checkbox is not relevant for the combobox.

To solve your issue, remove the combobox from the `ItemsControl` and have it stand on its own:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Synonyms}" DisplayMemberPath="Display"/>
```

Which tells the combobox to bind its `ItemsSource` to the data context which is unspecified, *which is fine*, so it then gets it's parent's data context. That process works its way *up* to each parent until it finds a bound data context (most likely the page's datacontext to a VM instance).

Assuming that the data context is valid at some point in the visual tree, it will bind to that instance and look for a property named `Synonyms`. From the  `Synonyms` property it will use that *as a list* to display items.

To show (display) text in the combobox (instead defaulting to the item's `ToString()`) the combobox will show the string from the item's property `Display`.

Giving a list of items in one drop down.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, is you should use a **ComboBox** as the root element, not **ItemsControl**. CompboBox is just a specialized version of ItemsControl.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Synonyms}" DisplayMemberPath="Display"/>
```

The longer answer.

ComboBox derives from ItemsControl, so you get all the features the base class, plus additional features.

ItemsControl (and its derived classes) provides a way of repeating a set of data in the UI.  The DataTemplate is where you specify what UI you want for each "row" of data in the Synonyms source.

What you are doing is asking Silverlight to create a separate ComboBox for each underlying data row.

You can still use a DataTemplate within the ComboBox.  Like this.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Synonyms}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--Display items in CheckBox-->
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Display}" 
                     Margin="10,0,0,0"
                     FontWeight="Bold"  />              
          </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```